# Sharepoint 2013 ListView using GridView

Tags: spgridview, ecb-menu

So I have this problem.
I have a list in the root site level.
But I want this list to be managed by some subsites.
For this reason I have to recreate some view of this list on different subsites, but
it must appear (the interface) as the default view of the list, smth like the same user interface of Sharepoint 2013:

[image: Sharepoint 2013 Default List Page]

Now I thought about Content Query Web Part, but I had difficulties on creating the grid with headers and the searching functionality.
So the only way I think I could manage it is by programming it.
So I started creating the spgridview, plus the Add function, and the search functionality, but I don't know how to create the menu on each item that is the command with 3 dots on each row. In sharepoint2010 we use SPMenuField, MenuTemplate and MenuItemTemplate. But what control of gridview to use here?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet got a chance to work with SP 2013. But if I had the same requirement in SP 2010,
I may go with XSLTListViewWebpart. You can specify the name of the List and the view to be used in the webpart. Here is an example of adding XSLTListview webpart to the page:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/08/programatically-add-xsltlist-view.html

Comment: I'll try it. And I'll let you know. Sounds like the best solution. Thank you so much.